# How to transfer system app (built-in app) from android to android?

Tags: root-access, file-system, system-apps, systemless-root

I have Collins dictionary in my Samsung Galaxy S6 edge which is System app (it can only be disabled, no uninstall option). I want to transfer this dictionary to my j7 mobile but it does not transfers through zapya, shareit or Bluetooth etc!. There are several apps which asks for root permission in order to transfer system app from android to android but i am unable to root my s6 edge mobile. Is there any easy way to transfer this app because this app is not found in playstore or it have a high price!

Comment: Use shareit or simalar apps to transfer the apk from one device to another

Comment: does not works! look my body

Comment: I guess I didn't see that ShareIt was among the apps listed. Try the methods suggested to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/how-do-i-get-the-apk-of-an-installed-app-without-root-access